# Laravel migration incompatible foreign keys

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've been told to remove the auto incrementing functionality of one of our tables, however this started to cause problems:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'limitCardId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'rolling_control_cards_limitcardid_foreign' are incompatible.")

Here are the keys in question:

PK `$table->integer('id');`

FK `$table->integer('limitCardId')->unsigned()->index();`

Relation `$table->foreign('limitCardId')->references('id')->on('limit_cards');`

I've read several other posts that suggested several solutions, however none solved my issue, here's a list of what i've already tried:

Defining this in my base table model:

```
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = false;
```

Adding
`Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` at the start of the `up()` method, and
`Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();` at the end, i've ran `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`.

As suggested, here's the stripped version of both tables,
Base table:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('limit_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('limit_cards');
    }
```

Related table:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rolling_control_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('limitCardId')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->unique(['controlCardNumber', 'limitCardId']);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('limitCardId')->references('id')->on('limit_cards');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rolling_control_cards');
    }
```

Comment: Are you running the migration on a fresh database?

Comment: ```php artisan migrate:fresh --seed```, Does that qualify as a fresh DB?
Otherwise no, the DB has records atm.

Comment: Dropped all tables, still nothing. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Yes, this command will drop all the tables and recreate them. Can you post the full migration of both `limit_cards` and `rolling_control_cards` tables?

Comment: @mdexp I'm not very confortable to post the migrations here (and it will get bloated), do you mind if post them in a chat with you?

Comment: No problems for me, but posting them here might help others with the same issue. Also S.O. chats will be public as well. Another way could be to post the stripped down migrations to show only `ids` and `foreign` relations of the two tables (nothing more, nothing less). Anyways, if you'd rather post them in a S.O. chat go on for that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will add stripped versions of the tables to the post.

Comment: At a quick glance: one's signed, the other's unsigned.  They should be the same.

Comment: @danronmoon You sir, are a genious! Do you mind posting your answer so i can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Y.Futekov I don't answer much anymore but I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for foreign key references to be compatible they must be of the exact same type, including their signedness.

`$table->integer('id');` creates a signed integer column by default.  Either make it unsigned to match `limitCardId` or make them both signed.

Answer (score 3):

**`limit_cards`**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('limit_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> `unsignedInteger` => UNSIGNED INT equivalent column.

**`rolling_control_cards`**

```php
Schema::table('rolling_control_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('limitCardId')->nullable();
    $table->unique(['controlCardNumber', 'limitCardId'])
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('limitCardId')->references('id')->on('limit_cards');
});
```

Comment: What i did to solve the issue by danronmoon suggestion is - I've made both keys
```->unsigned()->index();```

Comment: @Y.Futekov No problem. This will be a reference for other visitors.

Comment: @ Wahyu Kristianto The idea is for the PK of limit_cards to no longer be increments, just integer.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : Making "unsigned" will cause future errors if you want to switch to another RDBMS since "UNSIGNED" is for SQL only

```
Schema::create('rolling_control_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('limitCardId');

    $table->foreign('limitCardId')->references('id')->on('limit_cards');
});
```